# Getting the Row With the Max Value for a Column From a Union

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

## Tables

### forums

- forum_id
- name

### threads

- thread_id
- forum_id
- user_id
- added_ts

### thread_replies

- thread_reply_id
- thread_id
- user_id
- added_ts

### users

- user_id
- username

## The Problem

I want to return a list of forums with the most recent post for each. Efficiently. Part of the trouble is that posts are split among threads and thread_replies.

My first instinct is to get a UNION of threads and thread_replies with the data I need:

```
SELECT * FROM ((SELECT forum_id, thread_id, user_id, added_ts FROM threads t)
UNION (SELECT t1.forum_id, r.thread_id, r.user_id, r.added_ts FROM thread_replies r 
      INNER JOIN threads t1 ON t1.thread_id = r.thread_id)) messages;
```

Now I've got a list of all posts with a forum_id, thread_id, user_id and added_ts. My next instinct was to join this table on the forums table, but I don't see a clear way to pare this down to only the most recent value for added_ts for each forum, while still returning the rest of the required data.

```
SELECT * FROM forums f 
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT messages.*, users.username FROM
     ((SELECT forum_id, thread_id, user_id, added_ts FROM threads t) 
       UNION 
      (SELECT t1.forum_id, r.thread_id, r.user_id, r.added_ts 
       FROM thread_replies r 
       INNER JOIN threads t1 ON t1.thread_id = r.thread_id)) messages 
       INNER JOIN users ON messages.user_id = users.user_id 
       ORDER BY messages.added_ts) last_replies ON last_replies.forum_id = f.forum_id;
```

I tried GROUP BY forum_id, coupled with MAX(last_replies.added_ts), but those are the only two fields of the result set that I can select using group by and the aggregate functions, as best I can tell.

```
SELECT f.forum_id, MAX(last_replies.added_ts)
FROM forums f
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT messages.*, users.username
   FROM (
      (SELECT forum_id, thread_id, user_id, added_ts
       FROM threads t)
      UNION
      (SELECT t1.forum_id, r.thread_id, r.user_id, r.added_ts
       FROM thread_replies r
       INNER JOIN threads t1 ON t1.thread_id = r.thread_id)) messages
       INNER JOIN users ON messages.user_id = users.user_id
      ORDER BY messages.added_ts
        ) last_replies ON last_replies.forum_id = f.forum_id GROUP BY f.forum_id;
```

I think there might be a way to do this using ORDER BY added_ts DESC and LIMIT 1, but I can't seem to see how to make that work either. I hope to get some good ideas here that can steer me in the right direction.

## Solution

Based on the chosen solution below, I came up with this query:

```
SELECT f.*, last_replies.*, u.username 
FROM forums f 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (messages.forum_id) messages.*
    FROM (
        (SELECT forum_id, thread_id, user_id, added_ts FROM threads t)
    UNION
        (SELECT t1.forum_id, r.thread_id, r.user_id, r.added_ts FROM thread_replies r INNER JOIN threads t1 ON t1.thread_id = r.thread_id)
    ) messages
   ORDER BY messages.forum_id, messages.added_ts DESC
) last_replies ON last_replies.forum_id = f.forum_id
INNER JOIN users u ON last_replies.user_id = u.user_id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DISTINCT ON ... ORDER BY:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT

Comment: Edited the question to highlight how I used this solution.

Comment: +1 I didn't know "distinct on" existed. It works the same as mysql's "group by" without an aggregate function.